# ARMv8 Assembly, How to cast integer value to float value, and how to print it?

Tags: assembly, arm, printf, arm64, armv8

When I try to cast an integer into a float and print it out, the value stored in that register turns to 0.000000.

```
outI: .string "%d\n"
outF: .string "%f\n"

      mov        x20,      160
            
      mov        x1,       x20
      ldr        x0,       =outI
      bl         printf
            
      scvtf      s20,      x20      //cast x20 to float
            
      fmov       s0,       s20
      ldr        x0,       =outF
      bl         printf
```

When I try to run above code, The value printed out is:

```
160
0.000000
```

Did I give wrong print instruction?

Comment: Walk in a debugger and see what that instruction does in the registers.

Answer (score 3):

The `%f` format specifier for `printf` expects an argument of type `double`, but by passing a single-precision floating point value in `s0`, you are effectively passing `float` instead.

(In fact, variadic functions such as `printf` can never take an argument of type `float`.  If you try to pass a `float` argument to `printf` from C code in C, it will be [implicitly promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) to `double`, but of course assembly won't do that for you.)

So you need instead to get a double-precision floating point value in `d0`.  If you've already got a single-precision float in `s20`, then the simplest approach is to replace your `fmov s0, s20` with `fcvt d0, s20` to convert it to double precision.